# Animate google map markers

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I want to do achieve something like this [animation](http://www.tripomatic.com/trip-planner/#/?trip=*q29k939ka6k2)

Here when the user clicks/ hovers over any place in the list, the corresponding place is highlighted on the map in an animated fashion. How can i achieve this ?

I did some Google but could not find any documentation for it. Can anyone suggest some useful resource or links?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately you can't access the marker object with css because it's not a part of the DOM, it's part of the `canvas`. But you may use [custom overlays](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/overlay-simple) with custom styles to achive what you want.

For the pulse effect you can use CSS animations. You can find an example below;

```css
body {
    padding: 40px;
}
@keyframes pulse {
    0% {
        transform: scale3d(1, 1, 1);
        opacity: 1;
    }
    100% {
        transform: scale3d(2.2, 2.2, 1);
        opacity: 0;
    }
}
#pulse:before, #pulse:after {
    animation: 3s ease-out 0s normal none infinite running pulse;
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    border-radius: 24px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7) inset;
    content:"";
    height: 48px;
    left: 50%;
    margin: -24px 0 0 -24px;
    pointer-events: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    width: 48px;
    z-index: -1;
}
#pulse:after {
    animation-delay: 1.5s;
}
#pulse {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background: #ffffff url('http://www.blogher.com/files/imagecache/tiny_thumb/user_pictures/picture-196261.jpg') no-repeat center center;
    position: relative;
    border-radius: 25px;
    text-align: center;
    font: bold 14px/50px tahoma;
}
```

```html
<div id="pulse"></div>
```

Comment: Here the animation property that you have used does not works in IE-8 . how to make it work for earlier version